# Install python module only on home folder in server

Tags: python, ssh, module, server

I'm developing my master thesis on a university's server, so I have my account and I can log in and do all the stuff I want if I remain inside /home/myname/.

I'm developing some python scripts and now I want to integrate python with the octave module, which is not currently installed on the system, and , of course, I cannot do anything with `sudo apt-get install` .

How can I overcome this problem without asking to my teacher?

thank you all,

Fabio

Comment: Do it inside a "virtualenv" and install it with "pip install"

Comment: Can you explain a little more?

Comment: virtualenv is used to isolate your python dependencies from the sytem packages: check their official page for details on how to use it: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide.html and once your virtualenv is activated "source bin/activate", you can use "pip install oct2py" to install octave independently from your system and without permissions. (assuming you already have virtualenv installed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't copy python and pip. You should use a [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) to install project-specific packages. This is particularly useful in your use-case where you *can't* install things at the system level. Even if you could, virtualenvs are recommended so the dependencies of each project are isolated.

Here is a quick primer that should get you going.

#### Create the virtualenv

```
virtualenv ~/project/env
```

#### Activate the virtualenv

```
source ~/project/env/bin/activate
```

This will modify your bash prompt by placing the name of your virtualenv in parenthesis to indicate that your virtualenv is activated.

```
(env) hostname:current_folder user$
```

#### Install Packages into the virtualenv

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

#### Use the virtualenv

```
python script.py
```

#### Use virtualenv by default in a script

**script.py**

```
#!~/project/env/bin/python

print('hello world!')
```

Then from the command line

```
chmod ugo+x script.py
./script.py

    hello world!
```

#### Deactivate the virtualenv

```
deactivate
```

Comment: Thank you Suever, this solved my problem in an elegant way :) thank you

Answer (score 2):

Make yourself a local copy of python and pip, then you can install whatever modules you want and not have to worry about getting a sysadmin to help you. 
There are some good instructions [here](http://isezen.com/2011/09/02/how-to-install-locally-python-on-linux-home-directory/)

Go [here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/) to get the link to the version of python you need and substitute it in the instructions above.

In your .bashrc add alias and path to your local copy - you may need to modify this for your own situation:

```
alias python="~/bin/python" 

PATH=~/.local/bin:~/bin:$PATH
```

For the PATH - when you install local copies of modules through pip they by default go to ~/.local - change this if you prefer.

Begin your scripts with:

```
#/usr/bin/env python
```

so they use your preferred python version